# Convert Dataframe into Series to return directly the value in that row and column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm trying to convert a DF I have, so that it can return true a piece of code like this (`cat_totals` being a df):

```
assert_equal(cat_totals["Interdisciplinary"],12296)
assert_equal(cat_totals["Engineering"],537583)
```

For this, I'm supposed to filter the main dataframe (`df`) into a subset containing only the Subject and the Total number of students. Then I group by the subject (Major_category) and sum. The numbers are correct in my dataframe, but if I try to run the above code, it throws up an error. How can I convert the dataframe so that the above `assert_equals` returns True?

```
cat_totals = df[['Major_category', 'Total']]
cat_totals = cat_totals.groupby(['Major_category']).sum()
cat_totals['Total'] = cat_totals['Total'].astype(int)
display(cat_totals.head(10))
```

[image: This is the output of the above code and what the data looks like.]

With this the DF looks intuitively correct, but `cat_totals['Interdisciplinary']` does not equal the value I'm looking for. In the table, the number that corresponds to the Major is correct, so the calculation is correct, but the format of the return value does not seem right.

Any help would be much appreciated! I'm quite new to working with Pandas, so it's a bit of a struggle.

Comment: It's difficult to help without sample data as your description is hard to follow precisely.  However, I can say that if `cat_totals` is a dataframe then `cat_totals['Interdisciplinary']` will be a series.  And that will not be equal to a scalar.  There are ways to pick out which row, or the first row, or even to squeeze the dimensions if the length of the dataframe is 1.  However, it would make it easier for anyone trying to answer if you provided sample data and expected results. See [mcve]

Comment: @piRSquared thanks so much for the feedback! Yeah I figured out it needs to be a series, but I'm way confused about how to convert a whole dataframe into a Series? I did Google around a little, but it didn't help me too much in this particular problem. I also added in a screenshot of the data (the output) of the code fragment! Thanks for the answer and I hope I provided some context.